Can the Rust compiled node extension listen for notification events on the Mac system?
I want to implement an addon using Rust to expose an addListener API. When I modify the system's time zone, I can receive a callback.
using core_foundation_sys and neon
The code is as follows:
extern "C" fn notification_callback(
    _center: notification_center::CFNotificationCenterRef,
    _observer: *mut c_void,
    _name: notification_center::CFNotificationName,
    _object: *const c_void,
    _user_info: CFDictionaryRef,
) {
    println!("timezone_change");
}

fn init_notification {
  unsafe {
            let center = notification_center::CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter();
            let observer = &Observer as *const _ as *mut c_void;
            let name = CFStringCreateWithCString(
                kCFAllocatorDefault,
                b"kCFTimeZoneSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification\0".as_ptr() as *const i8,
                kCFStringEncodingUTF8,
            );
            let object = ptr::null();
            let suspension_behavior: isize =
                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately as isize;
            notification_center::CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(
                center,
                observer,
                notification_callback,
                name,
                object,
                suspension_behavior,
            );

            // Run the main loop to keep the application alive and responsive to notifications
            CFRunLoopRun();
    }
}
fn add_date_listener(mut cx: FunctionContext) -> JsResult<JsUndefined> {
    let cb_name_js = &cx.argument::<JsString>(0)?;
    let cb_name = cb_name_js.value(&mut cx);

    if cb_name == "timezone_change" {
        init_notification();
        TimeZoneChangeEvent::new(cx)
    } else {
        Ok(cx.undefined())
    }
}

fn create_date_module(cx: &mut ModuleContext) -> NeonResult<()> {
    let date = cx.empty_object();
    let get_timezone_fn = JsFunction::new(cx, get_timezone)?;
    let add_date_listener_fn = JsFunction::new(cx, add_date_listener)?;
    date.set(cx, "getTimeZone", get_timezone_fn)?;
    date.set(cx, "addListener", add_date_listener_fn)?;
    cx.export_value("date", date)?;

    Ok(())
}

#[neon::main]
fn main(mut cx: ModuleContext) -> NeonResult<()> {
    create_date_module(&mut cx)?;
    Ok(())
}


nodejs usage:
const addon = require('dist/x.node');
addon.date.addListener('timezone_change', () => {
  console.log(timezone_change);
})

print: timezone_change
But I can't do anything else because the main thread of Node.js is blocked.
I have tried the following:
Modify init_notification to the following code：
fn init_notification() {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        unsafe {
            let center = notification_center::CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter();
            let observer = &Observer as *const _ as *mut c_void;
            let name = CFStringCreateWithCString(
                kCFAllocatorDefault,
                b"kCFTimeZoneSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification\0".as_ptr() as *const i8,
                kCFStringEncodingUTF8,
            );
            let object = ptr::null();
            let suspension_behavior: isize =
                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately as isize;
            notification_center::CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(
                center,
                observer,
                notification_callback,
                name,
                object,
                suspension_behavior,
            );

            // Run the main loop to keep the application alive and responsive to notifications
            CFRunLoopRun();
        }
    });
}


The result is that no notification was received，How to achieve receiving notifications without blocking the main process of Node.js？
